# multiple versions of php on linux apache server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, moodle

I just launched a new EC2 instance and installed a LAMP server which installed PHP-7.

My plans for the server is to host a Drupal-7 and a Moodle-28 site.

Drupal is happy with PHP-7 but Moodle-28 will not cooperate with a version of PHP over version 5.

**Can anyone tell me:**

- if it's a good idea to install multiple versions of PHP
- how to direct different virtualhost to use different PHP versions

Comment: You will need a second virtualhost or https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_and_PHP7 use a other Moodle Version

Comment: Could you upgrade to Moodle 3.0? "PHP 7.0 can be used with Moodle 3.0.1, Moodle 3.1 and later releases"

Comment: I could upgrade to Moodle 3 but the plugins I need to use are written for Moodle 2. And, I am no expert at Moodle to rewrite/refactor the code